# Global variable defined in one function does not keep definition in another

Tags: mysql, testing, go

After some reading, I think I need this `TestMain(m *testing.M)` construct to setup my database. However when it comes to running a test, db is always **nil**. How do I fix this?

```
var db *sql.DB

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

        db, err := sql.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("DSN"))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("error opening database")
        }

        defer db.Close()
        log.Printf("here testing with %v", db)
        code := m.Run()
        log.Printf("finished test")
        os.Exit(code)

}

func Test_getRole(t *testing.T) {
        if db == nil {
                t.Fatalf("db is nil")
        }
}
```

Output is:

```
2018/05/02 19:10:14 here testing with &{{bugzilla:SECRET@tcp(example.com:3306)/bugzilla?multiStatements=true 0x7aba40} 0 {0 0} [] map[] 0 0 0xc42001e180 0xc4200740c0 false map[] map[] 0 0 0 <nil> 0x4e9850}
--- FAIL: Test_getRole (0.00s)
        main_test.go:32: db is nil
```

https://github.com/unee-t/processInvitations/blob/testfail/main_test.go#L43 is a link to the full piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your line `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("DSN"))` creates a local variable db (local to function TestMain). Instead use:

```
err := nil
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", os.Getenv("DSN"))
```

Comment: Argh... the err not being defined caught me. https://github.com/unee-t/processInvitations/commit/74bce5e090299ffcea221eacc6ce2a05d139d29d Hate that about go. Thanks! Let me know if you any other feedback on my code.

Comment: You're welcome! I would recommend changing the name to - "Global variable defined in one function does not keep definition in another". That way, several people having a similar issue would be able to quickly debug it. This problem would be relatively common in Go.